# Firefox adding newlines to clipboard content

Tags: html, css, firefox, clipboard

When displaying three `<div>` elements inline in Firefox, and then copying the outputted text to the clipboard, newlines are added between each element's text. This is not the case with Chrome, where it comes out as one row. Code I am testing this with:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">one</div><div style="display: inline-block;">two</div><div style="display: inline-block;">three</div>
```

Chrome: onetwothree

Firefox: one
two
three

Is there any way to force content from Firefox to stay on one line?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Where are you copying the divs from, and where are you pasting them?

Comment: @TylerH Here is a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/jsaeu3nh/

Comment: Did my answer ever end up working for you?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Those divs are inline for me on Firefox.

Comment: @TylerH That is correct. They are `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister So I'm failing to see how that "reproduces the problem" of **non-inline** divs that OP claims to be having.

Comment: @TylerH Please understand that OP is *not* having a problem of non-inline divs. OP's problem is that when they copy the text from the divs, the text gets copied to the clipboard in multiple lines, even thought the divs are all on one line. I think you may be understanding the question. To reproduce the issue, open my fiddle in Firefox, copy the text from all the divs, and paste it into a text editor. You will see that the text gets pasted on 3 lines instead of 1, which is not the expected behavior. It should be pasted on one line, like in Chrome.

Comment: In that case, yes OP was being unclear, and @ChristianN this is a bug in Firefox that you'll need to submit to Mozilla, if one already isn't filed. It exists in IE11 and Edge, as well.

Comment: Since `<div>` is a block level element I'm not sure who's right here (didn't find anything in specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `divs` to `spans` keeps Firefox's clipboard output all on one line for me (no newlines are inserted), like you are looking for.

**Live Example (run it, then try copying the text):**

```html
<span style="display: inline-block;">one</span><span style="display: inline-block;">two</span><span style="display: inline-block;">three</span>
```

Very interesting problem, by the way!

Comment: Keeping them as divs shows them in one line, too. The issue is with copying from the clipboard, not the HTML itself. http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/3dsfd2qf/

Comment: @TylerH That's what I mean, it keeps the clipboard output all on one line (when you copy text from the spans in Firefox, no newlines are inserted, which is the result OP is looking for). Perhaps I didn't make my answer clear enough?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved our problem and we found no other issues in switching from divs to spans in our case

Comment: @ChristianN Fantastic, glad I could help! Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark to the left so it turns green. Thanks!